# Complexity of EFL coloring of a set of lines

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings

Let $M$ be a set of straight lines. Define an EFL coloring of $M$ with $k$ colors as a function $f : P(M) \rightarrow \{ 1,2,\dots,k \}$,  such that if two intersection points $p_1, p_2$ belong to the same line, then $f(p_1) \neq  f(p_2)$. ($P(M)$ is the set of all intersection points of lines from $M$.)
Denote by  $\chi_E(M)$ the minimum number of colors needed for an EFL coloring of $M$. \

Question: Prove that the problem of finding $\chi_E(M)$ is NP-hard.\

Any helpful suggestion/hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your EFL terminology derived from the Erdos-Faber-Lovasz problem? Your problem is just equivalent to that problem I suppose, by putting all interesection points of one single line in a clique. Then, by [this breakthrough paper's](https://web.mat.bham.ac.uk/D.Osthus/Algo-Nov10.pdf) introductory disussions, and the randomized algoritthm they give, it should be quick to say it is NP-Hard, I suppose